# SKEmitter Error on iOS7 Device

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I've got a problem with SKEmitter.
RainParticle.sks is the file, here is the code:

```
let rainParticle = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "RainParticle")
```

...

```
    rainParticle.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height + 10)
    addChild(rainParticle)
```

It works on a simulator, but when I run it on my Iphone 4s, it throws me this error:

> 2014-11-01 21:31:33.227 AfraidGame[1541:60b] +[SKEmitterNode
>   nodeWithFileNamed:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x38c0454c
>   2014-11-01 21:31:33.232 AfraidGame[1541:60b] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '+[SKEmitterNode nodeWithFileNamed:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   class 0x38c0454c'
>
> nodeWithFileNamed - unrecognized selector?

can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

Specifically `init(fileNamed:)` its only  [Available in iOS 8.0 and later.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKNode/nodeWithFileNamed:)

Comment: Ok, that's good to know. So, any way I could just pop it into my xcode project with objective c that would not be difficult if I had no experience with it? Like a file that just places my emitter in the scene, if that scene is a swift file?

Comment: But wait, everything else written with swift and spritekit works in ios7. Is there any way this could work?

Comment: yes, im trying to find the reference to the sprite kit and swift support but didn't find it, so im editing the response…

Comment: boy, that throws me a lot of errors. Do you know an example code that I could use, source of some sort?

Comment: Want to write in ObjC or Swift?
Try [this](http://www.apress.com/9781430264392) and [this](http://www.apress.com/game-programming/ios/9781484204016) books, the first for ObjC, the second for Swift.

Comment: From what I know I can combine two files in one project. I want to write the emitter class in obj-c, everything else in swift.

Comment: Deleted the previous comment and here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/elkraneo/bb74a66f02fb3493a458) in ObjC. Its an example method for adding a particle emitter in your scene.

Comment: Thanks! But I've got two errors in "void" line: "Expected a type, Missing context for method declaration". What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Try this :-) Worked for me using Swift.

```
    let sksPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("RainParticle", ofType: "sks")
    let rainParticle: SKEmitterNode = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(sksPath!) as SKEmitterNode
   rainParticle.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height + 10)
    addChild(rainParticle)
```